# How to wrap output of watch command?

Tags: watch, fold

Consider the following command:

```
watch -d "ps -ef | grep java"
```

It gives following output:

```
kshitiz  11369 11285  0 Oct13 ?        00:06:02 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Didea.version==14.1.2 -Xmx512m -Dfile.e
```

The output beyond `-Dfile.e` is truncated or flows off screen. How can I scroll to see the output or word wrap it?

Using `fold` without watch:
[image]

Using `fold` with watch:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pipe the output to fold to wrap the output at a specified width (defaultly 80):

```
watch -d "ps -efww | grep '[j]ava' | fold -s"
```

- Use the `-w` flag of `ps` for wide output, and twice for unlimited output.
- `fold -s` breaks at spaces.
- Also notice the `grep` command. I changed `java` to `[j]ava`. This
  way the `grep` process will not match himself in the `ps` output.

Comment: Though fold seems to work well by itself. With `watch` the output is still getting cut at `-Dfile.e`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition:

You can also try specifying the width; this will make full use of your screen width.

In my case, the following gives a perfectly formed output. Do customize the width parameter as per you monitor/terminal size:

```
watch -d "ps -ef --width 1000 | grep java | grep -v grep  "
```